# getting a indexOutOfRangeException was unhandled error

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to read a text file titled "inventory.txt" and save it to different arrays. I get the indexOutOfRangeException was unhandled error.When i go through my code and hover over the "itembulkAmt" it shows information from a differnt line in the text file because some items dont have bulk amounts or prices such as the nintendo switch. I am hard stuck any help would be appreciated. this is what the text file looks like:

> silly putty,3.95,10,2.99
>   silly string,3.50,10,2.77
>   Nintendo Switch,429.99
>   Mario Kart (Switch),49.99
>   Code Jam Challenge (Switch),47.99
>   Fidget Spinner,6.79,5,5.98
>   Rubik's cube,9.10
>   'Programming Rules!' button,0.79,20,.47
>   'Programming Rules!' bumper sticker,0.99,20,.78
>   bottle o bubbles,.99

```
    'read and validate inventory text file
    Dim invntFile As StreamReader
    If File.Exists("inventory.txt") Then
        invntFile = File.OpenText("inventory.txt")
        Dim indexInvnt As Integer = 0
        While Not invntFile.EndOfStream
            Dim entirelineInvnt = invntFile.ReadLine
            Dim inventory() As String = entirelineInvnt.Split(","c)
            Dim itemName As String = inventory(0)
            Dim itemPrice As Double = CDbl(inventory(1))
            Dim itemBulkAmt As Double = CDbl(inventory(2))
            Dim itemBulkPrice As Double = CDbl(inventory(3))
            itemLabel(indexInvnt) = itemName
            priceReg(indexInvnt) = itemPrice
            amtBulk(indexInvnt) = itemBulkAmt
            priceBulk(indexInvnt) = itemBulkPrice
            indexInvnt += 1
        end while
     end if
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour] (also there are tools and help on the little toolbar for formatting posts)

Comment: You could easily handle this using Try Catch blocks

Comment: Some of the lines in your file do not contain 4 elements.  Your code will throw an exception on those lines.

Answer (score 2):

Not all of the items have three prices. Thus, inventory(2) and inventory(3) are throwing index errors as a result.